# A data resource "azurerm_virtual_network" has not been declared in module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a terraform that creates a Vnet and a VM inside one of the subnets.
To do that, I need to extract the subnetIDs from the VNet.

When doing that, I get the following error

```
A data resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" has not been declared in module.weu_vnet.
```

This is my file structure:

```
|_ main.tf
|
|_ modules
|  |_ spoke
      |_ vnet
         |_ main.tf
         |_ outputs.tf
      |_ vm
         |_ main.tf
```

the outter `main.tf`:

```
    module "weu_vnet" {
      source  = "./modules/spoke/vnet"
      ...
    }
    
    module "weu_vm" {
      source  = "./modules/spoke/vm"
      ...
      subnet_id = module.weu_vnet.vnet_subnet_ids[1]
    }
```

The `modules/spoke/vnet/main.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = local.vnet_name      
  subnet {
    name           = "vms"
  }
  ...
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnets" {
    name                 = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets[count.index]
    virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
    resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
    count                = length(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets)
}
```

The `modules/spoke/vnet/outputs.tf`

```
output "vnet_subnet_ids" {
  value = data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnets.*.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet"
```

is a resource, **not data source**. So you have to refer to it as a resource (not use `data.`). For example, instead of

```
virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
```

it should be

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
```

Or you want to use data source, not resource. Then it should be

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module has a lot of issues, unfortunately, there are so many ways of writing a vnet module which is why I will stop myself to write one here. However, I can highlight mistakes and share the documentation.

The first resource `azurerm_virtual_network` has at least the following issues:

- It is already missing a couple of `required` attributes [resource_group_name, address_space, and others]. refer to [azurerm_virtual_network](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network) to know all required attributes and examples of using this resource.

**Minimum required attributes are:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                    = local.vnet_name ## OR ## var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name     = var.resource_group_name
  location                = var.location
  address_space           = var.address_space
}
```

- It is also referred to incorrectly in the dependent resource `azurerm_subnet`. It should not be referred to as `data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name` as it is not a data source. The correct reference should be

```
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
```

- Terraform currently provides both a standalone Subnet resource, and allows for Subnets to be defined in-line within the Virtual Network resource. At this time you cannot use a Virtual Network with in-line Subnets in conjunction with any Subnet resources. Doing so will cause a conflict of Subnet configurations and will overwrite subnets. [ Copied from the official [azurerm_virtual_network](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network) resource page ]. Which means either you can create subnets inside the `azurerm_virtual_network` resource or with `azurerm_subnet` resource.

The better way would be to use the explicit `azurerm_subnet` resource. The **Simplest Subnet** resource would be like follows , feel free to loop using `count` of `for_each` whichever sounds fun and easy to you. The recommendation would be the `for_each` meta argument.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {

  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}
```

For complete `azurerm_subnet` resource attributes reference and examples please refer to [azurerm_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet).

Understand Data sources:
A data block requests that Terraform read from a given data source and export the result under the given local name. They are read-only objects and can also read resources deployed/managed out of terraform scope.

**Full documentation on data sources:**
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources

**`count` Meta Argument:**
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count

**`for_each` Meta Argument:**
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

And the most often forgotten question:
[**when-to-write-a-module**](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop#when-to-write-a-module)

Hoping that it helped.